# For Firestore which Dependencies needs to be added, to write Java code?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am writing code to Listen Data-Change in Firestore DB using Java code.
I have used maven to add below dependencies:

1. com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:0.32.0-beta
2. com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.8.0

But while writing code, I am not able to resolve below imports:

1. com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentChange
2. com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentChange.Type
3. com.google.cloud.firestore.EventListener
4. com.google.cloud.firestore.ListenerRegistration

What needs to be done or which dependencies needs to be added?

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with a Firebase project, all you need is the admin SDK:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.8.0
```

It has transitive dependencies on everything else required to make it work.  I wouldn't try to bring in Cloud dependencies, unless you absolutely know you need them for some reason.

Also, remove the imports that you currently have for `com.google.cloud.*` and instead use the objects of the same names exposed by the admin SDK that live in `com.google.firestore`.

Comment: Hi Doug, I removed com.google.cloud. Now, I am not able to find any API which will record a change on Firestore DB. My need is to register any write (create/update/delete) on Firestore DB to a text file with the info, which will further read by a separate application.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the way you're importing the Admin SDK.  I don't have any problems finding the relevant classes when working in IntelliJ with gradle.

Comment: What API can be used? I pulled the below code from GitHub:

Comment: db.collection("cities").whereEqualTo("state", "CA").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>()                     public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,@Nullable FirestoreException e) {
for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
switch (dc.getType()) {
case MODIFIED:
System.out.println("Modified city");
break;
}
}
if (!future.isDone()) {
future.set(snapshots.getDocumentChanges());
}
}


Issue with method addSnapshotListener, EventListener, getDocumentChanges, getType, getData